# Java Log4j2 converter category plugin add more than one custom fields to log

Tags: java, log4j2

I tried the examples in [Extending Log4j2](http://andrew-flower.com/blog/Create_Custom_Log4j_Plugins) and [Create Custom Pattern using log4j2 in java](http://learnjava-soa.blogspot.com/2015/06/create-custom-pattern-using-log4j2-in.html) and now I want to add two fields to the log. What changes do I need to do to get this?

Comment: Where's the code you've tried so far and what fields do you want to add?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to this manual https://logging.apache.org/log4j/log4j-2.2/manual/plugins.html#Converters

If you want several fields for example *time* and *name* you could create two separate Converters which will provide that data to the log.

For instance you have **MyNamePatternConverter**, here we can provide alias *whatIsMyName* and *myName*. In log pattern we can use any of those.

```
@Plugin(name="MyNamePatternConverter", category = PatternConverter.CATEGORY)
@ConverterKeys(value = {"whatIsMyName", "myName"})
public class MyNameConverter extends LogEventPatternConverter {

    protected MyNameConverter(String name, String style) {
        super(name, style);
    }

    public static MyNameConverter newInstance(String[] options) {
        return new MyNameConverter("My name Converter", "name");
    }

    public void format(LogEvent event, StringBuilder toAppendTo) {
        toAppendTo.append("Yuriy");
    }
}
```

and **TimePatternConverter**

```
@Plugin(name = "TimePatternConverter", category = PatternConverter.CATEGORY)
@ConverterKeys(value = {"timeIsNow", "timeNow", "now"})
public class TimeConverter extends LogEventPatternConverter {
    protected TimeConverter(String name, String style) {
        super(name, style);
    }

    public static TimeConverter newInstance(String[] options) {
        return new TimeConverter("Time Converter", "now");
    }

    public void format(LogEvent logEvent, StringBuilder toAppendTo) {
        toAppendTo.append(new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm").format(new Date()));
    }
}
```

We will put them two in separate package called *converters*.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration xmlns="http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/config"
               status="OFF" packages="converters">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="STDOUT" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="Time is now %timeIsNow and my name is %whatIsMyName, %m%n"/>
        </Console>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Logger name="org.apache.log4j.xml" level="all" />
        <Root level="all">
            <AppenderRef ref="STDOUT" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Provide log4j2.xml.

And create a sample Main class to test it.

```
public class Main {
    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(ResolverUtil.Test.class);
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        logger.info("Hello log4j2");
        logger.debug("This is debug message");
    }
}
```

This will produce such an output:

```
Time is now 20:40 and my name is Yuriy, Hello log4j2
Time is now 20:40 and my name is Yuriy, This is debug message
```

Comment: I have four custom appenders which I need the two fields for each (ConsoleAppender, RollingFileAppender, etc). Will that require writing 2*4=8 plugins or can I reuse by writing just 2 for each field?

Comment: Of course no, if you have 2 Converters (TimeConverter, NameConverter) then all your custom appenders will be provided with those 2 fields.